# How to lazy load HammerJS in Angular 9 project?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, hammer.js

I use HammerJS in my Angular project for a few gestures like `panleft` and `panrigth` in lazy load component. When I build app, lazy load component is in separate bundle, but `hammer.js` stay in `node_modules` in main bundle. And it works as expected. But how to load `hammer.js` in separate lazy module to reduce main bundle size?

I use Angular 9 with Angular Material. HammerJS is not required for material since ng9.

To install HammerJS (and it works with ng9) I:
1. run `npm install --save hammerjs`
2. add to `main.ts` - `import 'hammerjs'`
3. import `HammerModule` to `app.module.ts` (required for ng9)
also I have custom config in `app.module.ts`:

```
@Injectable()
export class HammerCustomConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  overrides = { 'pinch': { enable: false }, 'rotate': { enable: false } } as any;
}
```

that provided like `{ provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: HammerCustomConfig }`

I tried and it DOESN'T work:
1. move `import 'hammerjs'` to lazy load module (but `hammer.js` repalced to bundle of lazy load module)
2. move `HammerModule` to lazy load module
2. move `HammerModule` with custom config to lazy load module
4. 1 + 2
5. 1 + 3

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to have HammerJS as part of only one lazy loaded module?

Comment: @Vojtech yes, right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving `import 'hammerjs'` from `main.ts` to lazy load **COMPONENT** resolve this problem.
Import of `HammerModule` and custom config should stay in `app.module.ts`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of how the module (in my case "Carousle Module") looks like.

Leave the `HammerModule` in your main module ( `app.module.ts` ) imports.

```
import { HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, HammerModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CustomHammerConfig } from './hammer-config';


import 'hammerjs'; // <-- import it here (not in your main.ts)

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HammerModule, // <-- put it only here (not in your AppModule)
  ],
  exports: [CarouselComponent],
  providers: [
    // config may be provided in module where needed or in app.module
    {
      provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
      useClass: CustomHammerConfig,
    },
  ],
  declarations: [CarouselComponent],
})
export class CarouselModule {}
```

---

In bundle analysis, you may see the hammer is part of feature chunk (module) and not the main module.

[image: build analysis]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but in this case, gestures don't work in component (

Comment: adjusted the answer to not confuse anyone